# How to change jqplot cursor tooltip size?

Tags: jquery, jqplot

I use jqplot for render graph. How to change text size for cursor(not highlighter) tooltip and do its bold?

```
cursor: {
              style: 'crosshair',
              show: true,
              zoom: true,
              showTooltip: true,
              followMouse: true,
              showTooltipDataPosition: true,
              showVerticalLine: true,
              useAxesFormatters: true,
          },
```

Answer (score 0):

.jqplot-cursor-tooltip  Styles applied to the cursor tooltip

http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqPlotCssStyling-txt.html

Comment: Thanks. I just redefined css styles:

    .cursor-size {
         font-size: 14px;
    }
     
   .jqplot-cursor-tooltip {
        font-size: 1em;
        font-weight: bold;
   }